# Script para pasar imágenes desde tabla mysql a archivos en servidor

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando volcar masivamente imágenes guardadas en una tabla mysql a archivos en el servidor, jpeg en este caso. Las imágenes son de tipo **blob**. Utilizo dos archivos. El primero para iterar la tabla y el segundo para extraer la imagen del registro actual.

Archivo 1: busca_imagenes.php

```
<?php
require_once "../model/personas.php";
/* Aqui comenzará la iteracion */
$Id_persona = 1;
$Orden = Personas::getImagenOrden($Id_persona) + 1;
$Destino = "/repo/imagen/$Id_persona.$Orden.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg( "muestra_imagen.php");
imagejpeg( $image, $Destino);
?>
```

Archivo 2: muestra_imagen.php

```
<?php
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=1.jpg");
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
require_once "../model/personas.php";
$Id_persona = isset($_GET['IDP']) ? trim( $_GET['IDP']) : 1;
$P = Personas::get( $Id_persona);
echo $P['imagen'];
?>
```

Esta es la salida

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in D:\xampp\htdocs\Patronato\controller\busca_imagen.php on line 7

Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): '../view/muestra_imagen.php' is not a valid JPEG file in D:\xampp\htdocs\Patronato\controller\busca_imagen.php on line 7

Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\Patronato\controller\busca_imagen.php on line 8

Supongo que la función **imagecreatefromjpeg** esta interpretando el código php del archivo **muestra_imagen.php** y no su resultado. Como puedo solucionar esto? Alguien tiene una mejor solución a esta necesidad? Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma, dejo el script por si le sirve a alguien

```
require_once "../model/personas.php";
if( $Lista = Personas::lista()){
    for( $i = 0, $c = count( $Lista); $i < $c; $i++){
        $Orden = Personas::getImagenOrden( $Lista[$i]['id']) + 1;
        $Destino = "../repo/imagen/".$Lista[$i]['id'].".$Orden.jpg";
        if( !is_null( $Lista[$i]['imagen'])){
           file_put_contents( $Destino, $Lista[$i]['imagen']);
           echo Personas::guardaImagen( $Lista[$i]['id'], $Destino, 1, 1);
        }
    }
    echo "Terminó $i personas";
}else{
    echo "No hay personas";
}
```